# Rails date comparison; date greater or equal to days ago

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, date, comparison, activesupport

A date in my database looks like this: `2012-07-23`

I am trying to see if the date is older than 7 days ago and less than 14 days ago or see if the date is greater than 14 days ago, but am having no luck..

Here is my code:

```
def progress_report_status_check(date)
    progress_date = date.to_date
    seven_days = 7.days.ago.to_date
    fourteen_days = 14.days.ago.to_date

    if seven_days > (progress_date - 7.days.ago.to_date) or (progress_date - 14.days.ago.to_date) < fourteen_days
      "due"
    elsif (progress_date - 14.days.ago.to_date) > fourteen_days 
      "overdue"
    end 
  end
```

Comment: Are you using Rails? Ruby doesn't have days method. You need ActiveSupport for that

Comment: yes sorry, I forgot to add that in.. I am using Rails 3

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
def progress_report_status_check(progress_date) # Pass in a date
  if (progress_date < Date.now-14.days)
    "overdue"
  elsif (progress_date < Date.now-7.days) 
    "due"
  end 
end
```

or (less readable)

```
def progress_report_status_check(progress_date) # Pass in a date
  (progress_date < Date.now-14.days) ? "overdue" : ((progress_date < Date.now-7.days) ? "due" : "") : "" 
  end 
end
```

Depending on your usage you may want to create named scopes, say:

```
scope :overdue where(:progress_date < Date.now-14.days)
scope :due where(:progress_date < Date.now-7.days)
```

Then your calling code can be something like

```
def progress_report_status_check(progress_date) # Pass in a date
  self.overdue? ? "overdue" : self.due? ? : "due" : ""
  end 
end
```

Comment: I ended up having to use `Time.now.to_date` ... kept getting `undefined method now` on Date... but that works like a charm!!!

Comment: Sure.  Date's a bit weird too as it's automatically included in rails (so you see it in rails console) but not in ruby so you don't get to use in the IRB prompt (unless you include it).  That has confused countless.

Comment: When you want to play in a console, always use `rails c` ;)

Comment: I know this is old, but Date.now is undefined.  The correct way to do this is `Date.today - 6.days`

Comment: Use either `Date.today` or `DateTime.now`

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer uses an undefined method on the Date class.  This is correct:

```
def progress_report_status_check(progress_date) # Pass in a date
  if (progress_date < (Date.today-14.days))
    "overdue"
  elsif (progress_date < (Date.today-7.days)) 
    "due"
  end 
end
```